# QWebEngineView does not find some libraries which are installed

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtwebengine, qtwebview

To solve a display problem I was suggested to use `QWebEngineView`.
I inserted
`from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView`
in the script which when executed emits:

```
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
ImportError: libQt5Positioning.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


# locate libQt5Positioning.so.5
/root/.cache/pyinstaller/bincache00_py38_64bit/libQt5Positioning.so.5
/root/PycharmProjects/alltogether/build/exe.linux-x86_64-3.8/lib/PyQt5/Qt5/lib/libQt5Positioning.so.5
/root/PycharmProjects/extract/build/exe.linux-x86_64-3.9/lib/PyQt5/Qt5/lib/libQt5Positioning.so.5
/root/PycharmProjects/personal/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/lib/libQt5Positioning.so.5
/root/anaconda3/lib/libQt5Positioning.so.5
/root/anaconda3/lib/libQt5Positioning.so.5.9
/root/anaconda3/lib/libQt5Positioning.so.5.9.7
/root/anaconda3/pkgs/qt-5.9.7-h5867ecd_1/lib/libQt5Positioning.so.5
/root/anaconda3/pkgs/qt-5.9.7-h5867ecd_1/lib/libQt5Positioning.so.5.9
/root/anaconda3/pkgs/qt-5.9.7-h5867ecd_1/lib/libQt5Positioning.so.5.9.7
/usr/lib/insync/libQt5Positioning.so.5
/usr/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/PySide2/Qt/lib/libQt5Positioning.so.5
/usr/lib/wingide-personal6/bin/runtime-qt5.5/lib/libQt5Positioning.so.5
/usr/lib/wingide-personal6/bin/runtime-qt5.5/lib/libQt5Positioning.so.5.5
/usr/lib/wingide-personal6/bin/runtime-qt5.5/lib/libQt5Positioning.so.5.5.1
/usr/local/lib/personal/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/lib/libQt5Positioning.so.5
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/PySide2/Qt/lib/libQt5Positioning.so.5
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/lib/libQt5Positioning.so.5
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/lib/libQt5Positioning.so.5
```

I use `python3.8` without `venv`. If I use `venv`, it doesn't even find QtWebEngineWidgets

Comment: `PyQt5-WebEngine` is an extra library that should be installed as well, i.e. with `pip`

Comment: @cards ~# pip install PyQtWebEngine
Requirement already satisfied: PyQtWebEngine in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQtWebEngine-5.12.1-py3.8-linux-x86_64.egg (5.12.1)
Requirement already satisfied: PyQt5>=5.12 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from PyQtWebEngine) (5.15.6)
Requirement already satisfied: PyQt5-sip<13,>=12.8 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from PyQt5>=5.12->PyQtWebEngine) (12.9.1)
Requirement already satisfied: PyQt5-Qt5>=5.15.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from PyQt5>=5.12->PyQtWebEngine) (5.15.2)

Comment: @RyanDay From your comment above, it seems that you're using Qt5.12, while some of the packages listed above seems to come from a much older version. Some of those also belong to different Python versions and installations, so it would help to know *which* Python you're using in order to understand if the PyQt installation for *that* install and eventually fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through Pycharm I solved the problem by updating PyQtWebEngine from 5.12 to 5.15